# How to open multi terminal on Ubuntu server?

Tags: 12.04, server

I have installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server** .

How can i run more than .sh file in the same time 
(opening more than terminal)

I can use it on **desktop** version but i use **server** version.

Is it possible? if yes how can do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Ubuntu has 7 ttys, on Server they are all command line (desktop the 7th is for X use)
You can switch between then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

This would allow you run your script in 7 different sessions.

You can also background processes by starting them as normal, but appending an <kbd>&</kbd> to the end e.g.

```
yourscript.sh &
```

If your script does not terminate itself you will need to locate the pid and kill it, for more detail on killing read:

- [How to terminate a background process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-terminate-a-background-process)

Comment: but when i used & after sudo myscript.sh   what happened is the same terminal started not in background any idea? or i'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It's perfectly when you need multiple terminals. Specially when you are connected via `ssh` and you don't want to start another session.

You can, for example, run a command in it, detach, go to another machine, reattach and everything is still there.

Another similar application that provides the same is [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Linux will process one process at a shell at a time, which means script running in your scenario.

At a same time if you need to do some other tasks through shell .. you can use other consoles from tty 1 to tty6.

tty 7 is GUI [ currently using Desktop ].

Move to tty 1 from current desktop. press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F1</kbd>  . After that use  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F2</kbd>  to go to tty 2 and follow upto   <kbd>F3</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd>   <kbd>F6</kbd>  and  <kbd>F7</kbd>  for GUI