# How to use multiple terminals on Ubuntu server?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS in MacOS device through VirtualBox.

How can I open more than one terminal and navigate through them?

I already came across a similar question asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472829/how-to-open-multi-terminal-on-ubuntu-server) but it didn't work with me. I believe it is because I am running the Ubuntu server from mac in VirtualBox.

Comment: Use the screen command. There no need to split the screens but well maybe you find the read useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/980910/how-do-i-start-screen-with-multiple-splits-directly-from-the-command-line

Comment: @Videonauth I am using Ubuntu Server from Virtual Box, tried both links and the command in the second link didn't work in my Mac Keyboard

Comment: The first answer in the second link. I used the commands "Alt + Ctrl + F1" to "F7" and they didn't work with me. This is the link "https://askubuntu.com/questions/472829/how-to-open-multi-terminal-on-ubuntu-server"

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+alt+fX in virtualbox (where X stands for 1-7).

Comment: @Videonauth I tried sudo apt-get install screen and it shows me that I have the screen already installed to the latest version. How can I split the terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69892/discussion-between-videonauth-and-mazin-almaskari).

Comment: @Videonauth Thank you. It worked, I replaced shift with fn key. and it solved it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [`byobu`](http://byobu.co/) with `sudo apt-get install byobu` and use it. It is more user-friendly, than `screen`.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for a terminal multiplexer. A couple of popular ones are tmux and screen. Here's a quick introduction to tmux: https://hackernoon.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-tmux-8d784c404340

Comment: @derHugo: The gist of the answer, albeit short, is in the first two sentences. As I understand it the link is just a suggestion on how to get started with one of the previously recommended tools and not essential to the answer.